# AMD + Backbone + JSDoc3 best way to document

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, amd, jsdoc3

I'm looking for the best way to document my code, but I don't find anything.

I've see others topics, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166343/how-do-i-document-amd-backbone-project-with-jsdoc3), but there all doesn't resolve my problem.

I have something like this:

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function (Backbone) {

    /**
     * @module models/products
     */

    /**
     * Product model
     * @class
     */
    var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
        /** @lends Product.prototype */

        /**
         * Some method
         * @param {String} name - Name of something
         * @return {something}
         */

         someMethod: function () {
             // ...
         }

    });

    /**
     * Products collection
     * @class
     */
    var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        /** @lends Products.prototype */

        /**
         * @type {Product}
         */
        model: Product,


        /**
         * Some method
         * @param {String} name - Name of something
         * @return {something}
         */

         someMethod: function () {
             // ...
         }

    });

    return Products;

});
```

I need to generate a legible documentation, where *Product* and *Products* classes apears into the *models/products* module, but I get the module clear and the classes by separate.

I suppose there is someone who has gone through this issue.

Thanks.

PD1: I really read other posts, I'm not trying to duplicate questions.

PD2: Sorry my poor english :S

Comment: This way of asking for recommending tools and ways is considered off-topic on this site. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…[...]
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is", Wy you thinks it's off toppic? I'm asking the correct use of a "commonly used by programmers" tool. I don't asking for a better use, I asking for the correct use.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [doc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html), I understand that your problem can be solved by moving the following code to the top of the file:

```
/**
 * @module models/products
 */
```

I understand that since you have written `@module` inside a anonymous function its just get ignored.

Comment: Can anyone verify if this is the issue. The main author is away I guess.

Comment: No, if I move the "module" to top of file, I have the module without the class, I tried it (if you check the thread I share in the description), using the "lends" on the factory without results.